# Bundle error, undefined method 'tsource'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Help, I can't get past this bundler error:

```
Gemfile:1:in `build': undefined method `tsource' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0xb73c9e04> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `definition'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:101:in `check'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.3/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Gemfile:

```
tsource 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', :git => 'http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2.git'
gem 'devise'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'json'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your `Gemfile`:

```
tsource 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Should be:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

(Notice the missing `t`.)